# How do we express the Schrödinger wave function using the Hankel transform instead of Fourier transform?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform

What if we use the [Hankel transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform) instead of the Fourier transform?
$$\Psi(x)=a\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\Phi(k) e^{ikx} dk $$
$$\Phi(k)=b\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\Psi(x) e^{-ikx} dx .$$
How would the probability density function of the Schrödinger wave be, would it give us the same results as the Schrödinger wave using the Fourier transform?
$$\Psi_{n}(x)=a\int_{0 }^{\infty }\Phi(k) J_{n}(kx)k  dk $$
$$\Phi(k)=b\int_{0 }^{\infty }\Psi_{n}(x) J_{n}(kx)x dx .$$
The reason for this question is that I can express any wave as a continuous sum of Henkel functions and this is very similar to the continuous Fourier transform.

Answer (score 0):

Your formulas for Hankel transform make no sense. You can compare them with those at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform

In general, you can use the Hankel transform, but only for $x>0$, unless you redefine the Hankel transform somehow. So you can use it, e.g., in a cylindrical system of coordinates for the radius.